# How to run the specified testng case by code?

Tags: java, testng, testng-annotation-test

How to run the specified `testNG` case by code? The following code:

```java
public class TestNGTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("test  ########");
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        System.out.println("test2 ************");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        TestNG testSuite = new TestNG();

        testSuite.setTestClasses(new Class[] { TestNGTest.class });
        testSuite.setDefaultSuiteName("setDefaultSuiteName");
        testSuite.setDefaultTestName("setDefaultTestName");
        testSuite.run();
    }
}
```

This would run both the test cases. How to specifically run "test2" only?

Expected output:

```
test2 ************
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the classes prefixed with `Xml` to achieve this:

```java
XmlClass xmlClass = new XmlClass(TestNGTest.class.getName());
// now mention the methods to be included. You may use setExcludedMethods depending on the requirement.
XmlInclude method = new XmlInclude("test2");
xmlClass.setIncludedMethods(List.of(method));
// or xmlClass.setExcludedMethods(List.of("test"));
```

Now create xml suite and xml test:

```java
XmlSuite suite = new XmlSuite();
suite.setName("suite");

XmlTest test = new XmlTest(suite);
// internally, the test method is also added to the suite object
test.setName("sample");
test.setXmlClasses(List.of(xmlClass));
```

Final create `TestNG` object:

```java
TestNG t = new TestNG();
t.setXmlSuites(List.of(suite));
t.run();
```

**Note:** `List.of` is a method available only in java 9 or above. If you are using a lower version, then you may use `java.util.Arrays.asList`

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by adding a method interceptor like this:

```java
public class TestNGTest implements IMethodInterceptor {

    @Test
    public void test() {

        System.out.println("test  ########");
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {

        System.out.println("test2 ************");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        TestNG testSuite = new TestNG();

        testSuite.setTestClasses(new Class[] { TestNGTest.class });
        testSuite.setMethodInterceptor(new TestNGTest());
        testSuite.setDefaultSuiteName("setDefaultSuiteName");
        testSuite.setDefaultTestName("setDefaultTestName");
        testSuite.run();
    }

    @Override
    public List<IMethodInstance> intercept(List<IMethodInstance> methods, ITestContext context) {
        return methods
                .stream()
                .filter(iMethodInstance -> "test2".equals(iMethodInstance.getMethod().getMethodName()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```